# app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).single('photo')) return "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to use multer to upload file

I use latest multer (v.0.18)

I configure the app this way

```
  var express = require('express')
                , multer = require('multer')
                , app = express() 
                , routes = require('./routes');

  app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
       rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
       return filename+Date.now();
      },
        onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
      },
        onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
        done=true;
      }
 }).single('photo'));
```

and it keeps returning "Undefined is not a function"
(referring to the .single() )

if I remove the .single to 

`multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });`

this error message is gone, but of course the file itself becomes undefined then nothing is uploaded.

Work on it a day long, man!
obviously need help :'(

Answer (score 1):

This is how I use `multer`, hope this helps you: 
(Create a directory and add the pictures to it with every `POST` request).
This is in the `routes.js` (or any name of the file you posted the code of):

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage( {
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        var destFolder =__dirname + '/../uploads/' + req.params.id;
        //create folder if does not exists
        if (!fs.existsSync(destFolder)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(destFolder);
        }

        //set folder where files will be populated
        cb(null, destFolder)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        //set the names file within the folder
        //as the original name of the file
        cb(null,file.originalname);
    }
});
```

And then I use a service (`fileUploadService.js`) to call it like so:

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function (files, uploadUrl) {

            var fd = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fd.append('file', files[i]);
            }

            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            })
            .success(function () {
                console.log("images files upload success");
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log("images files upload fail");
            });
    }
}]);
```

This works perfectly for me, hopefully you can adapt it too. I understand the frustration since it also took me some time to get right.

Comment: Hi, thanks but it seems I have to used angular.js too, don't I? I have used swig for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

You have an old version installed. The API you're trying to use was only introduced in recent versions (probably starting with v1.0.0).

You might check that your `package.json` isn't restricting what version of `multer` gets installed.

I should also point out that you will need to modify your `multer` options a bit when you upgrade: `onFileUploadStart` and `onFileUploadComplete` no longer exist and `rename` is now `filename` (but with a different, async function signature).

Comment: I have installed version 1.1.0 now. It stops saying "undefined is not a function. However, when I do JSON.stringify(req.file), it printed "undefined"

Comment: Then most likely something is wrong with your request, for example: the `name` attribute of the file input is either wrong or missing completely, or the `Content-Type` (`enctype` form attribute) is not `multipart/form-data`.